# Report for Failed SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-agent

I'm trying to write a SQL Server query that will return the failed jobs for the last XX minutes/days etc.

I basically want one record, for each job that failed, with a concatenation of the messages for each step. I have written the below query, but due to the grouping, I get one concatenated message for the WHOLE job, not just this particular instance - and I can't work it out. Any assistance would be appreciated :)

```
WITH    failedJobs
          AS ( SELECT   j.name ,
                        DATEADD(SECOND,
                                ( run_time / 10000 ) * 3600 + ( ( run_time - ( ( run_time / 10000 ) * 10000 ) ) / 100 )
                                * 60 + run_time - ( ( run_time / 100 ) * 100 ),
                                CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_date), 105)) AS run_datetime ,
                        js.step_name ,
                        jh.job_id ,
                        jh.step_id ,
                        jh.instance_id ,
                        jh.sql_severity ,
                        jh.message
               FROM     msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
               INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS js ON js.job_id = j.job_id
               INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh ON jh.job_id = j.job_id
               WHERE    jh.run_status = 0)
     SELECT fj.job_id ,
            STUFF(( SELECT  CHAR(10) + message
                    FROM    failedJobs fj2
                    WHERE   fj.job_id = fj2.job_id
                  FOR
                    XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') AS message
     FROM   failedJobs fj
     WHERE  DATEDIFF(DAY, run_datetime, GETDATE()) <= 2 -- Last 2 days
     GROUP BY fj.job_id;
```

Comment: Could you add the output you get, versus the output you expect in your question?

Comment: So you don't want to see the output of the succeeded steps? Maybe you want to add jh.sql_severity <> 0 you only see the failed steps.